# Android layout <include /> tag

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to use include tag in my xml layout to recycle a common layout part.

Android documentation says i can modify some attribute of imported layout, for example

```
<include layout="@layout/topbar" />
```

Include topbar layout without specify width and height.

```
<include layout="@layout/topbar" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Include topbar layout with specific width.

So, in my topbar layout, i've a textview without text, can i set textview text from include tag like below?

```
<include layout="@layout/topbar" android:text="Hello world" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: Development questions are off topic here please see the FAQ http://android.stackexchange.com/faq , you'd be best off asking this on http://StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 4):

No, you'll need to do this in code.  In your activity, call findViewById() to find the TextView, then call TextView.setText() to set the text.